# Youtrack, Is it possible to add comment for other user using rest api

Tags: php, rest, bitbucket, youtrack

Youtrack, Is it possible to add comment for other user using rest api?
I'm able to add notes in youtrack task but can't find method of how to add notes for other user,  I have admin privileges and will use this in youtrack and bitbucket integration.

Anyone know how?

references : 
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD6/YouTrack+Permissions+Reference
http://forum.jetbrains.com/thread/YouTrack-36

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean you need to add comment on behalf of another user? If it's the case, then such an option is not available. Could you please share whole scenario?